# Attempting to use logical "OR" within "ViewData"

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a situation where I am passing parameters to a partial view using `ViewData`, however **sometimes** there won't need to be a parameter passed. In that situation, I simply want it to fall back to a default.

So the actual View *usually* looks something like this ...

```
<div>
   @Html.Partial( "templates/form/slots", new ViewDataDictionary { { "slots", "First.Slots" } })
</div>
```

and then the partial that is being rendered looks like this...

```
<div class="form-group">
   <h3>Slots</h3>
   <!-- lots of other happy HTML -->
   <select ng-model="@ViewData["slots"]"></select>
</div>
```

Surprisingly, that works just fine. But I am having a bit of a snag with the `||` syntax. I would like it to fall back onto a default of `"Model.Slots"` if no value is given to the ViewData. I thought that would be as easy as ...

```
<select ng-model="@( ViewData["slots"] || "Model.Slots" )"></select>
```

But that isn't working, citing the error ...

> The '||' operator cannot be applied to instances of 'object' and 'string'.

I know I'm close, I'm just struggling with the exact syntax regarding razor. Is there a way to get this kind of expression without contorting and using a full-sized extension method?

Comment: You probably want to use the coalescing null operator `??` rather than `||` as the result of or is a Boolean (plus you'd have to ensure both operands were a compatible type so casting the object would be necessary). So try `viewdata["slots"] ?? "Model.Slots"`. You shouldn't need to cast. Coalescing null chooses the first non null value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [null coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx), not the logical or.

```
<select ng-model="@( ViewData["slots"] ?? "Model.Slots" )"></select>
```

Unlike Javascript (and other dynamic languages) where the construct `object || default` is legal, C#'s typing system does not allow it because it expects boolean operands. The `??` operator though does what you want, it falls back to the second operand if the first one is `null`.

Comment: Yes! That is the one! Thank you. Will award credit as soon as the 11 minute timer is up. I was just botching the razor syntax. It is actually pretty confusing to remember when to use what combination of `@` and parenthesis in razor, for me.

Comment: The reason I want this is because I am doing a lot of partial views just to split up the components, since I re-use them in many places. Most of the time, I want them to be looking at the root of the model - but I've encountered a situation where I need to use some of the widgets in a nested structure, so I am needing to be able to optionally define the "root" for that certain rendering of the partial view. This worked perfectly!

Comment: Though now that I say that, it isn't working quite like I want. But that's for a different question. 2 minutes until I can award credit for this one. Thanks again.